# Datastream unstable connection when connected with private site-to-site connection to RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-bigquery, amazon-rds, google-datastream

We have set up a private site-to-site connection between our Google Cloud project and AWS RDS (MySQL), which serves as our main database. The connection is established through datastream, allowing us to push MySQL data to BigQuery. However, we have been experiencing persistent issues with datastream becoming unstable and reporting that it is unable to connect to RDS. When we test the connection to RDS, it appears to be working fine. This problem lasts for a few days continuously, during which datastream remains very unstable.

Eventually, datastream automatically recovers, but this issue has been recurring and needs to be addressed.